# automation of audit report of new ingestion files into s3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

How can we automate of generating an audit report containing file name and timestamp of new ingested file into aws s3 using python or any other methods.

minimizing manual process and automating the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [S3 event notification to trigger an AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) function to process the file. Please note that Lambda has a maximum execution time of 15mins. If you need more time to process the file, you could spin up an EC2 instance or an ECS Task if you prefer to use container.

Comment: in lambda do we need to use custom python code for any functions

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.